# Spring and Ehache : Cachemanger

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I am trying to use `Eh-Cache 2.8` with `Spring 4.2.3`, I found that we can use spring ehcache manager but in another blog I found that we can directly use Ehcache manager directly in spring and use Ehache annotataion as well . I am confused as to which is the better and right approach.
Below is the Code Configuration :

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cache='http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache' 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <cache:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />

    <bean id='ehcache'
class='org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean'
        p:configLocation='classpath:ehcache.xml' p:shared='true' />

    <bean id='cacheManager' class='org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager'
        p:cacheManager-ref='ehcache' />

</beans>
```

Code where I'm adding data to cache

SubscribeData.java this class gets data from MQ and adds it to cache

```
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;

public class SubscribeData implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    CacheManager chachemanager;

    public void onMessage(Message m) {
        TextMessage message = (TextMessage) m;
        try {
            Cache cache = chachemanager.getCache("cache");
            cache.put("key", message.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In `SubscribeData.class` I'm getting data from xml and adding it to cache , it this right way to do it. I know I'm not using cache annotation here , but there are other methods where I'm using it.

Below are my queries

1) As mentioned above should i use spring ehCache or ehCache directly an example is below
ehCache as Cache manager instead of spring ehCache manager

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class CacheConfig {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehcacheCacheManager = ehCacheManagerFactoryBean().getObject();
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehcacheCacheManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheMgrFB = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();

        cacheMgrFB.setShared(true);
        cacheMgrFB.setCacheManagerName("cacheManager");
        cacheMgrFB.setConfigLocation(ehCacheConfigResource);
        return cacheMgrFB;
    }
}
```

2) how to add data to cache in void method i.e methods that dont return anything and just want to add data to cache.

Comment: `Cache cache = chachemanager.getCache("cache");` Shouldn't it be `EhCache` here instead of `Cache`?

Comment: I am a newbie , i dont know much

Comment: It's okay, we all are learning here. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: @user2004685 as i know the way to put data in cache is to add cacheable or cacheput  on top of method which get data from DB or any data source so  and returns some , the returned data is stored in cache but i have method which just gets data from DB and does not return any value and wants to store data how do it do that , the code is have written SubscribeData  is good enough

Answer (score 0):

1. For your first question, you are not really using the Ehcache API in the second example, just writing code that is equivalent to the Spring XML from above. So in that context, unless you have a good reason to have code for this, I would stick with XML as it will make updating the configuration easier if it needs to be one day.
2. You actually provide the answer yourself in your `SubscribeData` sample. You cannot use a void method as the proxy doing the wrapping would not have access to the data that needs to be published.

Comment: Thanks for inputs , You mean to say my java configuration is same as the xml that i have defined ? ... I though i was configuring the acutal ehcache's cachemanager as the cachemanager for application in java config

Comment: Not really, you are still using the Spring types for this, `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean` and `EhCacheCacheManager`